# query string not working in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the following code I used `{!! URL::route('editCatForm',['id'=>$row->id]) !!}` to go to named route editCatForm with query string `?id=5` or whatever that comes dynamically on `$row->id`

```
@foreach($categories as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $count++ }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->category_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->category_status }}</td>
        <td><a href="{!! URL::route('editCatForm',['id'=>$row->id]) !!}">edit</a> / <a href="{!! URL::route('destroyCat',$row->id) !!}">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

My route for this is

```
Route::get('editCatForm/{id?}',array('uses'=>'Categories@editCat','as'=>'editCatForm'));
```

but still it shows url like

```
http://localhost/projects/brainlaratest/editCatForm/2
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/projects/brainlaratest/editCatForm?id=2
```

The route points to function

```
public function editCat($id)
{
    $catEdit = Category::find(Input::get('id'));
    $categories = $this->getCat();
    return view('categoriesAddForm',compact('categories','catEdit'));
}
```

What may be the issue that query string isn't working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format of your url is `editCatForm/{id?}` so if you provided id it will try to replace `{id}` with your number and you will get `editCatForm/5`.

Problem is in your controller action. `function editCat($id)` already takes `$id` from route - you should replace `Input::get('id')` with just `$id`.

`URL::route(...)` can be replaced by just helper function `route(...)`.

If you want get rid of `/id` you can remove `{id}` from your route and then `route(...)` will just add `?id=5` instead of `/5`. You would have to remove `$id` argument from function and get id by `Request::input('id');`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,do I need to include `Use Request;` or something on top of my controller to use request? and I need to make url `editCatForm` instead of `editCatForm/{id?}` ,is it?

Comment: Yes, you have to put `use Request;` on the top. If you really do not want to have `/id` then `Route::get('editCatForm' ...)` is what you want.

Comment: Tons of thanks sir!Your solution really did worked!!

Answer (score 1):

This is how route() function is supposed to work.

If you insist on having the query string then you need to append the ?=2 to the URL manually and you cannot do routing based on this.

One way of building the query string is like this

```
$params = array('id' => 5);
$queryString = http_build_query($params);
URL::to('projects/brainlaratest/editCatForm?'.$queryString )
```

Answer (score 0):

The Routing is correct. Your problem is to getting the `$id` in the action.

Since, you have passed `$id` in route parameter, you can capture the segment `$id` inside your action.

```
public function editCat($id)
{
    $catEdit = Category::find($id); // edit this line.
    $categories = $this->getCat();
    return view('categoriesAddForm',compact('categories','catEdit'));
}
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters